# How do I use Cognito to update user pool attributes with android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm making an android app and have created a user in my user pool with the Amplify framework. The documenation for amplify says that making calls to get/set attributes isn't built yet, so I guess I need to use cognito directly.
I now want to set attributes such as name once the user signs up.

Right now I have this code, but I'm not sure what to do from here.

```
    CognitoUserAttributes attributes = new CognitoUserAttributes();
    attributes.addAttribute("testAttribute", "testValue");
```

Also I'm struggling to figure out how to use cognito in android, the only documentation I can find is this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index-all.html

Answer (score 1):

This functionality has not yet been implemented in Amplify for Android but is scheduled to be finished in the near future, as noted in [this documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/user-attributes/q/platform/android).  Please check back to the documentation for updates on availability.

In the meantime though, you can still use Amplify.  Just access the underlying AWSMobileClient through the authentication [escape hatch](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/escapehatch/q/platform/android), which does support passing custom attributes.    See [this documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/auth/getting-started/q/platform/android) for more details on how exactly to use AWSMobileClient.